# MySQL: The correct way to calculate standard deviation

Tags: mysql

I have the weight of different people.

The average is:

```
select avg(weight) as avg_weight
from table;
```

But what's the difference between `stddev()` and `std()`?  Is it possible to get the standard deviation from avg_weight?

Is this the correct way:

```
select stddev(weight)
from table;  /* -> is here where the function avg(weight) included? */
```

Or do I need something like this:

```
select stddev(avg(weight))
from table;  /* (but this does not work) */
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question could have way too many answers. Why don't you read up on it from here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-standard-deviation/

Comment: can you please say me if this is correct please
select stddev(weight) from table;

Comment: @Melisa Hi, I have the same question as you, could you please tell me how you fix your issue, use `stddev(weight)` or `stddev(avg(weight))`? Thanks so much for any reply

Answer (score 13):

In MySQL, they provide four different functions related to standard deviation.  They could have provided only two `STDDEV_POP` and `STDDEV_SAMP` (population vs sample S.D.).  They provide the other two for compatibility with standard SQL (`STD`) and Oracle (`STDDEV`).

Here is the description from [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_std):

**STD(expr)**

Returns the population standard deviation of expr. This is an extension to standard SQL. The standard SQL function STDDEV_POP() can be used instead.

If there are no matching rows, STD() returns NULL.

**STDDEV(expr)**

Returns the population standard deviation of expr. This function is provided for compatibility with Oracle. The standard SQL function STDDEV_POP() can be used instead.

If there are no matching rows, STDDEV() returns NULL.

**STDDEV_POP(expr)**

Returns the population standard deviation of expr (the square root of VAR_POP()). You can also use STD() or STDDEV(), which are equivalent but not standard SQL.

If there are no matching rows, STDDEV_POP() returns NULL.

**STDDEV_SAMP(expr)**

Returns the sample standard deviation of expr (the square root of VAR_SAMP().

If there are no matching rows, STDDEV_SAMP() returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use AVG inside STD, or any other aggregate functions. Each one in a column.

```
SELECT
AVG(table.column) AS average_,
STD(table.column) AS std_,
etc....
FROM
table;
```